# Map method doesn't work When I try duplicating <MenuItem />

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm using material ui.

I try to duplicate `<MenuItem />` as much as data.

So I wrote this code:

```
            <FormControl fullWidth>
              <InputLabel>JobArea</InputLabel>
              <Select
                autoFocus
                label="JobArea"
                sx={{
                  width: "70%",
                }}
              >
                {props.jobArea.map((jobArea: any) => {
                  <MenuItem key={jobArea.id} value={(jobArea || {}).name || ""}>
                    {(jobArea || {}).name || ""}
                  </MenuItem>;
                })}
              </Select>
            </FormControl>
```

But the code was nothing response.

It seems like `<MenuItem>` wasn't read on program.

When I use `console.log` like this

```
                {props.jobArea.map((jobArea: any) => {
                  {
                    console.log((jobArea || {}).name || "");
                  }
                  <MenuItem key={jobArea.id} value={(jobArea || {}).name || ""}>
                    {(jobArea || {}).name || ""}
                  </MenuItem>;
                })}
```

Outcome was:

[image]

So I guess map method is fine but problem is `<MenuItem>`.

From Github they use map method like me.

https://github.com/mui/material-ui/issues/18494#issuecomment-680500105

What is deference between my code and others.

Please help me.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your lambda passed to map has a statement body since it’s enclosed in curly braces. You need to `return` the menu item or use an expression lambda without curly braces.

Comment: Ohhhh... That's problem... Thank you!!!! I got it!!